# PHP sort function works differently on localhost then on a website server

Tags: php, html, sorting, scandir

I have this website: http://www.oemsynthetics.com/order.php

On the bottom you see the product images.What I do is I have product images in a folder and use php scadir() to save their names.At the beginning of each name I put a number so that I can sort the array.For example, one of the images name is 1motor-oil.jpg . When I use the sort function on localhost it sorts by the numbers normally and works good. On the website server though it doesn't sort at all.
I don't know why. Can someone please help me?
Here is the code that I use:

```
<?php
//By Product Part 
    $byProduct = "http://amsoil.com/shop/by-product/";
    $byEquipment = "http://www.amsoil.com/shop/by-equipment/";
    $dirEqui = "./assets/byEquipment";
    $dirPr = "./assets/byProduct";
    $imagesPr = scandir($dirPr,0);//save all the image names in alphabetical order(I used numbers for ordering in a way that I want)
    $imagesEqui = scandir($dirEqui,0);//save all product images in alphabetical order by equipment
    //i = 2 because the the first files in directory are . and ..
    sort($imagesEqui, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);//sort by equipment
    sort($imagesPr, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);//sort the array naturally
   for ($i=2; $i < count($imagesPr); $i++) { 
       if(preg_match('/\.(jpg|png)/',$imagesPr[$i])){
        //Delete .jpg from the file name
            $product = $imagesPr[$i];
            $product = preg_replace('/\.(jpg|png)/','',$product);
            $product = preg_replace('/\d+/','',$product);
        //Create links and pictures
            echo "<a href='".$byProduct.$product."?zo=".ZO."'><img class='products' src='".$dirPr."/".$imagesPr[$i]."'></a>";
       }else continue;
   }
?>
```

Thanks everyone in advance for the help.

Comment: What PHP do you have on your local machine and website server? The SORT_NATURAL and SORT_FLAG_CASE parameter works only on PHP 5.4 and upwards. I suspect you might have an older version on your website server. Run phpinfo(); in order to know which PHP version you currently have.

Comment: OHH I just ran it on the website server and as it turns out I have 5.3.13.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, That's the reason why it is not working. More info on the sort patameters here:
`http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php`